# How to generate random between 0 and 1 in Netlogo with uniform distribution

Tags: random, netlogo, uniform-distribution

I am trying to do some testing and stumble across the problem that  (random 2 = 0) does always give me much more 0 than 1s, even though it is supposed to be uniform distribution. Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend you provide us with more information so that we help you. Can you share your code? Also, what's your methodology? How many trials are you running? I am very familiar with NetLogo's RNG, and I also did some testing with NetLogo Desktop 6.3 on MacOS right now. I can't replicate your problem. I created a global `num-heads` and a go procedure with the following code `set num-heads num-heads + random 2`. The number of tails would automatically be `ticks - num-heads`. A quick test with 16 million ticks and the heads-tails ratio is a dynamic equilibrium approaching 1.

Comment: What sort of statistical test have you used to validate your impression that the output is non-uniform?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that is just a perception bias. You can check it out using the following code (that you can just copy-paste in the command center). Using `n-values` I repeat `random 2` 100000 times , then I use `filter` to only take the 0's, and finally `length` to count how many 0's these are.

```
show length filter [i -> i = 0] (n-values 100000 [random 2])
```

Running it 5 times I got 50068, 50028, 50051, 49991, and 50085 which gives no indication at all for there to be more 0's than 1's